# Row number in dataframe based on multiple parameters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, row

I wish to find the row number, based on multiple parameters. I have made this test matrix:

```
data=
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "1"  "a"  "0" 
[2,] "2"  "b"  "0" 
[3,] "3"  "c"  "0" 
[4,] "4"  "a"  "0" 
[5,] "1"  "b"  "0" 
[6,] "2"  "c"  "0" 
[7,] "3"  "a"  "0" 
[8,] "4"  "b"  "0"
```

Then I want to get the row number where

```
data[,1]==1 and data[,2]=='b'
```

Comment: `which(data[,1]=="1")` and `which(data[,2]=="b")`

Comment: `which((data[,1]=='1') & (data[,2]=='b'))`